# prevent file copying not via permissions

Tags: filesystems, ssh-keys, timestamp, checksum

Is there any way I can prevent a file from being copied?

I don't mean via the file system, but I mean by somthing that must change if the file was copied, like some sum or timestamp

My goal is to create an ssh key that cannot be duplicated
(yes I know, use a smart card... I'm looking for an alternative).

I don't mean to actually prevent the copying, but only to be able to varify that the file is a copy

Comment: Depending on the filesystem you may be able to detect if its been copied based on the "Access Time" - problem is there are legitimate reasons for accessing the file, so you would need to cross-correlate this with usage - and, of-course, there are ways to circumvent changing the access time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

Depending on your environment/OS/architecture/level of expertise, it may be possible to use something like Apparmour or SELinux to frustrate attempts to copy it or for it to be read except with specific programs.

If you need a private key which can't (easily) be copied, you will need to imbed it in silicon along with logic to do decryption such that the private key is never exposed – and even then it can be copied if someone is skilled enough and has access to the silicon and some very specialist hardware (that's how some Pay TV systems were hacked).